# Yellow and brown spots on leaf tip

Tags: agriculture

On a barley farm, there are yellow and brown spots on leaf tips.

Possible causes:

- Some kind of parasite
- Weather condition
- Bad seed

  - Looks like some farms using the same seed are affected

What might be the actual cause? What could be the solution?

[image: leaf]

[image: leaf]

[image: leaf]

[image: leaf]

[image: leaf]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you contact your local government agricultural authority.

It looks like the barley crop might be infected with a pathogen, such as a fungus.

It could be a form of [barley rust](https://agriculture.vic.gov.au/biosecurity/plant-diseases/grain-pulses-and-cereal-diseases/rusts-of-barley).

Different regions of the world have different [forms of rust](https://grdc.com.au/resources-and-publications/groundcover/ground-cover-issue-105-july-august-2013/barley-rust-diseases-in-focus).

Your local agricultural authority should be notified in case the outbreak poses a bio security risk in your region.